# Trying to install nasm-2.1108 but getting permission deny

Tags: macos

Trying to install my nasm version as 2.11.08 but when i hit the "sudo make install" im getting error like this

```
$ sudo make install
mkdir -p /usr/bin
/usr/bin/install -c nasm /usr/bin/nasm
install: /usr/bin/nasm: Operation not permitted
make: *** [install] Error 71
```

how can i resolve this problem im running Elcapitan on my mac.

current nasm version:

NASM version 0.98.40 (Apple Computer, Inc. build 11) compiled on Aug 17 2015

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User-provided binaries should get installed to `/usr/local/` (or more specifically `/usr/local/bin`) to avoid any versioning conflicts with standard applications/binaries. There should be an option to set the install directory to `/usr/local` when you run `./configure` in your build directory.

PS: In OS X before El Capitan, it was rather easy to install to `/usr/bin` nevertheless. With El Capitan, Apple has introduced SIP to prevent these kind of modifications. There are ways to disable SIP, but I recommend to install to `/usr/local` instead.

Comment: i disabled sip because i couldnt figure out how to change configure file thanks for advice, right now with disabling SIP i upgraded nasm version